# JPA2 PrimaryKey vs Oracle Primary key

Tags: oracle, jpa-2.0

Is it possible that oracle table has a composite primary key oracle sequenceid +createtimestamp but the @Entity class  we have just the @id (sequenceid) primary key ? Timestamp we are adding for the purpose of table partitions which we use for purging later. At the time of storing the entity we will add the timestamp value all the time. From the data point of view id alone is primary key for the record in this case. Can I create entity with primary key as id alone?

Comment: "PriamryKey"? Are you sure you spelled that right?

Comment: PrimaryKey i mean :-)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you have to create composite primary key in @ Entity class. You can as per below example

```
@Entity
@Table(name="RELEASE_PERSON")
@IdClass(ReleasePersonPK.class)
public class ReleasePerson implements Serializable {

@Column(name="ORDER_NO", nullable=false, precision=2)
private Integer orderNo;

@Id
@Column(name="RELEASE_ID", insertable=false,updatable=false)
private long releaseId;

@Id
@Column(name="PERSON_ID", insertable=false,updatable=false)
private long personId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID", referencedColumnName = "PERSON_ID")
private Person person;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "RELEASE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
private Release release;
```

And your Id Class will be look like below

```
@Embeddable
public class ReleasePersonPK implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -6286499269052596345L;

private Person person;

private Release release;
```

In my example in ReleasePersone table we will have  composite primary key from rRelease(ID) and Person (Person_id).

Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thankyou. My question is more about whether we can have composite keys on oracle and with a non composite key on jpa @Entity classes.

Answer (score 0):

Ｔhe answer is yes. as you said that the id will be unique in the table, it's definitely ok that just put sequenceId as PK in the entity. If you don't use hibernate to create the table or update the columns of table, it doesn't care what actually in the database.